# name of tables & views in stored procedure in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, metadata

I have a stored procedure, I want to know the name of the tables and views use in that stored procedure, can any one suggest how can I do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you build and use dynamic SQL in your stored procedures, the only way to do this is to go in and read it yourself (which, trust me, really sucks).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sp_depends` but this depends on the dependency information being up to date.

Running `sp_refreshsqlmodule` on all objects in the database can update this if there is any missing dependency information.

Comment: Sorry for the edit - I thought this was my answer, and was trying to add a link ;-)

Comment: @Cade - Thanks for the edit. Edit Ha Ha Feel free to either leave it in or take it out as you wish!

Answer (score 5):

There are [several techniques](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1294)

[I use sys.sql_dependencies and sp_refreshsqlmodule to ensure that the dependency information is up to date before querying the metadata.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839425/sql-server-relationships-buried-in-stored-procedures-rather-than-schema/1840663#1840663)

Answer (score 1):

```
select
so.name,
sc.text
from
sysobjects so
inner join syscomments sc on so.id = sc.id
where
sc.text like '%ROLES%'-- name of the table
```

[Find Sp form database which is related to(using) table XXX](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/02/find-sp-form-database-which-is-related.html)